# How to record and plot outcome of RAND excel

Tags: excel, random

I have a column of numbers generated by `RAND()`, if the number is `>.5` I -1 in the next column and if it is `<.5` I +3 in the next column

Summing the `+3` and `-1` values gives me a total.

As the RAND() numbers change all the time what I would like to do is record the SUM each time and plot it to create a distribution graph. How can I do this?

Comment: If you want to keep your trial results static you basically have two options: copy and paste the results manually after each trial, or write a little VBA to do the same.

Comment: @andyholaday thanks Andy, I assumed as much, I can't write any VBA, would this be simple to do?

Answer (score 0):

for this ;

> RAND() numbers change all the time 
>   you may pause it by Formula > calculation > manual. (:

and for your if(rand()) function.. seems not to cover if the rand() generates EXactly 0.5000000 .

Hope this helps.. ( :